# Bootstrap datepicker update method incorrect format

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I spend lot of hours wondering what wrong with my datepicker. I do init datapicker like this

```
if (jQuery().datepicker) {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker({
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
     rtl: App.isRTL(),
     orientation: 'right',
     autoclose: true
   });
}
```

It's worked perfectly when i click on datepicker dropdown calender. But when i use method update or setDate, the result is wrong. i tried

```
$('#mydate').datepicker('update',new Date(2016, 2, 28));
$('#mydate').datepicker('setDate',new Date(2016, 2, 28));
$('#mydate').datepicker('update','28-03-2016');
$('#mydate').datepicker('update','03/28/2016');
```

Non of them is work. All of them result 03/28/2016. what i expected result is 28-03-2016

Really appreciate any idea...

Comment: Hi Adrian i don't see any problem with your code its working exactly as you wanted. I have created Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/wm268btt/ for your code. Please have look.

Comment: @Prakash thank for your effort. Would you tell me datepicker version do you used?

Comment: I used bootstrap-datepicker-1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prakash, who made me realize there's nothing wrong with datepicker js. The only wrong thing is me. My mistake is, i used styled datepicker html like this

```
<div class="input-group input-medium date date-picker" id="datepicker-mydate">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mydate" readonly>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn default" type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Then init component like this

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  orientation: 'right',
  autoclose: true
});
```

And do set value using this.

```
$('#mydate').datepicker('update',new Date(2016, 2, 28));
```

That i should use is like this.

```
$('#datepicker-mydate').datepicker('update',new Date(2016, 2, 28));
```

Case closed.